# Perl: assignment within scalar and string matching (regex)

Tags: regex, perl, scalar

I understand the general aim of the following piece of code (i.e. sum up the numeric part of the string, e.g.  for currstr="3S47M" then seqlength=50).

But could someone explain me what is happening line by line ?

In particular, I have issue to understand what value `where` is holding at each turn. More precisely, I don't understand the part with the `scalar` function ("scalar($RLENGTH = length($&), $RSTART = length($`)+1)") ?

Is it correct that the assignment of `RLENGTH`and `RSTART`take place inside `scalar` ?

Why using comma-separated assignment within `scalar` ? What does it mean ? And what is then the result of its evaluation ?

If anybody could help, I will be very very grateful !

Thanks

Erica

```
  my $seqlength=0; 
  my $currstr="3S47M";

  my $where = $currstr =~ /[0-9]+[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]/
    ? scalar($RLENGTH = length($&), $RSTART = length($`)+1) : 0;
  while ($where > 0) {
    $seqlength += substr($currstr, ($where)-1, $RLENGTH - 1) + 0;
    $currstr = substr($currstr, ($where + $RLENGTH)-1);
    $where = $currstr =~ /[0-9]+[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]/
      ? scalar($RLENGTH = length($&), $RSTART = length($`)+1) : 0;
  }
```

edit: what is the purpose of `RSTART` ?  why writing `scalar($RLENGTH = length($&)`will not work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```perl
$where = $currstr =~ /[0-9]+[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]/
  ? scalar($RLENGTH = length($&), $RSTART = length($`)+1) : 0;
```

is equivalent to

```perl
if ($currstr =~ /[0-9]+[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]/) {
   $where = scalar($RLENGTH = length($&), $RSTART = length($`)+1);
} else {
   $where =  0;
}
```

`scalar` is useless here. The expressions is already in scalar context. Simple parens would do.

When `EXPRX, EXPRY` is evaluated in scalar context, both `EXPRX` and `EXPRY` are evaluated in turn, and it results in the result of `EXPRY`. As such, the above is equivalent to

```perl
if ($currstr =~ /[0-9]+[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]/) {
   $RLENGTH = length($&);
   $RSTART = length($`) + 1;
   $where = $RSTART;
} else {
   $where =  0;
}
```

---

Note that `[M|D|N|X|=|S|H|N]` is a weird way of writing `[MDX=SHN|]`. The duplicate `N` and `|` are ignored. In fact, `|` is probably not supposed to be there at all. I suspect it's supposed to be `[DHMNSX=]`.

---

If I understand correctly, the code could have been written as follows:

```perl
my $currstr = "3S47M";

my $seqlength = 0; 
while ($currstr =~ /([0-9]+)[DHMNSX=]/g) {
   $seqlength += $1;
}
```

The following might even be sufficient (though not equivalent):

```perl
my $currstr = "3S47M";

my $seqlength = 0; 
while ($currstr =~ /[0-9]+/g) {
   $seqlength += $&;
}
```